# MeasureSpecs passed to onMeasure indicate the full parent size instead of the remaining available space

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-constraintlayout, android-wrap-content

I'm observing an issue where the `onMeasure` method of my custom view is receiving a `MeasureSpec` that corresponds to the full parent view's size, instead of the remaining available space. This happens when the view's `layout_width/height` attributes are equal to `wrap_content`. This issue prevents me from calculating the actual custom view's size correctly.

The issue is best explained by showing some minimal reproducible example code, and stating the actual vs. the expected results.

I have a CustomView widget that is simply a red-bordered rectangle. I overrode its `onMeasure` method like this:

```kotlin
override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    // Log the parameters to debug
    val widthSpecString = MeasureSpec.toString(widthMeasureSpec)
    val heightSpecString = MeasureSpec.toString(heightMeasureSpec)
    Log.d("------", "width=$widthSpecString, height=$heightSpecString")

    val width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
    val height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height)
}
```

(NOTE: I know this is an extremely oversimplified `onMeasure` method, but remember this is just a minimal reproducible example, and I'm more interested in the `widthMeasureSpec` and `heightMeasureSpec` parameters passed in.)

I have the following layout:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <View
    android:id="@+id/topView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="300px"
    android:background="@color/gray_transparent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  />
  <com.customviewsizedemo.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/customView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

which produces the following screenshot

[image]

and the following debug logs:

```
D/------: width=MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 1080, height=MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 1706
D/------: width=MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 1080, height=MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 1706
D/------: width=MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 1080, height=MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 1706
D/------: width=MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 1080, height=MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 1706
```

So far so good. From the logs, we can see that the area that the red-bordered rectangle occupies is `1706` pixels high. Since the gray view on top of it is `300` pixels high, we also know that the whole screen's height is `1706` + `300` = `2006` pixels high.

Now the interesting part: if I change the layout such that the custom view's `layout_width` and `layout_height` is `wrap_view`, something weird happens. That is, if I change the layout like this:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <View
    android:id="@+id/topView"
    ...
  />
  <com.customviewsizedemo.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/customView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  <----------------- Change here
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <----------------- Change here
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

we get this screenshot (observe that the bottom border of the rectangle is now offscreen):

[image]

And we get these logs:

```
D/------: width=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 1080, height=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 2006
D/------: width=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 1080, height=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 2006
```

**THE ISSUE**: `heightMeasureSpec` is equal to `AT_MOST 2006`. This doesn't make sense, because actually, the red-bordered rectangle should be *at most 1706 pixels high*. The gray view on top of it hasn't gone away: it's still occupying space that should be respected, but it doesn't seem to be respected/accounted for.

Why is the `heightMeasureSpec` equal to the full parent (screen) height? What can I do so I receive the correct value in the `onMeasure` method?

In case it's needed, here's the full minimal reproducible example (MRE): https://github.com/HectorRicardo/CustomViewSizeDemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `wrap_content` on a view does not, by default, constrain the view to its constraints. Your XML will wrap the content of the custom view and center the result between the top and bottom constraints. Centering will place the top of the view above its top constraint and below its bottom constraint. What you will see in logcat of a Nexus 6 API 31 emulator is the following.

> width=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 1440, height=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 2112
> width=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 1440, height=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 2112

If you want *ConstraintLayout* to honor the top and bottom constraints on your custom view you will need to add the following to the XML for the custom view:

```
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```

With this added, you will see the following:

> width=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 1440, height=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 2112
> width=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 1440, height=MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 1812
> width=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 1440, height=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 2112
> width=MeasureSpec: AT_MOST 1440, height=MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 1812

This is what displays:

[image]

Which, I believe, is what you expected. Also, as you state, you could simply set the view's height to `0dp`.